# Using an ODBC source in a lookup transformation - Any alternatives?

Tags: ssis

So I'm trying to use my ODBC data source in a lookup transformation in an SSIS package. However the only option I see is either an OLEDB source or a cache. Are there any third party applications which support ODBC for a lookup transformation which you guys know about?

Answer (score 1):

We couldn't find one so we use caches unfortunately